# new skype will not install in lucid due to dependency on libqt4-network 4:4.8.0

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, skype

today I was not able to log into skype in lucid as the newest version of skype is now required.  Running the deb package gives a dependency error that libqt4-network 4:4.8.0 is required.  Lucid (ubuntu 10.04) doesnt have that version.  Can I install that version of the QT lib from a newer version of ubuntu?  How?

Answer (score 0):

That would probably be very difficult, because newer versions of that package depends on newer versions of several other packages etc.

Sounds like it's high time to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version. The desktop packages of Lucid are no longer supported.